# How to fix "NoMethodError" when method_missing is defined for given class?

Tags: ruby

I have a class called RubyCsvRow, which holds a row of a CSV file, in a hash. I am using method_missing to allow any column to be used as a function to return the value of the row at that column. However, I get a method_missing error when I run I attempt to use it.

I wasn't sure exactly what was happening, so I replaced the call to one with a call to class.

```
m = RubyCsv.new
m.each{|row| puts row.class}
```

I edited the method missing in RubyCsvRow so that I could see what happens when it prints and see the name of the missing method:

```
def self.method_missing(name, *args, &block)
      puts "Called Method Missing"
      puts name.to_s
end
```

The return only confused me more.

```
Called Method Missing
to_ary
RubyCsvRow
Called Method Missing
to_ary
RubyCsvRow
```

It calls method missing. I don't know why it prints name as to_ary, which when I searched I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467395/whats-the-difference-between-to-a-and-to-ary), but I am not sure when it is being implicitly converted or why.

I searched around and have looked at these links. The labels where why I thought they didn't fit.

[I have my private variable defined as a :attr_accesssor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582608/undefined-method-error-ruby)

[Mine is a method of a class and I am using it like one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358039/ruby-nomethoderror-but-why)

[I am calling my method after defining it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072355/undefined-method-nomethoderror-ruby)

[I am not sure about this one. I am already converting my symbol to_s, but I had trouble determining if this fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977038/ruby-method-missing-return-no-method-error)

[Why I decided to format my each method in RubyCsv the way I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080007/how-do-i-add-each-method-to-ruby-object-or-should-i-extend-array)

```
class RubyCsvRow
    attr_accessor :values

    def initialize(start)
      @values = start
    end 

    def self.method_missing(name, *args, &block)
      if @values.key?(name.to_s)
        @values[name.to_s]
      else
        puts "No Column with name: ", name.to_s, " found!"
      end
    end

    def to_s
      self.inspect
    end
end

r = RubyCsvRow.new({"one" => "dog", "two" => "cat" })
puts r.one
```

RubyCsvRow is used in RubyCsv's each, but I get the same error with just this code. I can post the RubyCsv code, but this is the minimum code to reproduce the error.

I get a NoMethodError for one instead of printing dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `def method_missing` instead of self. You call method on instance not class it self.

If you define method with `self` you define the method as class not instance. In your code you create new instance of *RubyCsvRow* Class and you need to define `method_missing` as instace method.

**Modify code here:**

```
class RubyCsvRow
  attr_accessor :values

  def initialize(start)
    @values = start
  end

  # Define method missing on instance
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    return @values[name.to_s] if @values[name.to_s]
    # return my error message
    "No Column with name: #{name} found!"
  end

  def to_s
    inspect
  end
end

r = RubyCsvRow.new({ "one" => "dog", "two" => "cat" })
puts r.one
# => dog
puts r.test
# => "No Column with name: test found!"
```

BTW: If you need the original error message use `super` in `method_missing` method

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  return @values[name.to_s] if @values[name.to_s]
  # call original method
  super
end
```

Comment: Would using super be more Ruby? Would it call Object's method_missing?

Comment: If you wanna to call original method missing and get original error message, you should call super. This will call the original method from object.